# Jquery-Relatively animate DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I have `$("#myDiv").animate({right: "-200%"}, 1000)` which is enough to send a div out of the body. But that testing screen was 4:3. Now, I am testing the same page on a 16:9 screen and I can still see a part of that div. The div is 640px-wide.

So how can animate it in jquery with something like `$("#myDiv").animate({right: "(zero point of the currentbody)-640px"}, 1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your element is absoutely positioned, you can calculate the width of your div and then you can apply

right: -[the width of your div]

Because right: 0; will stick the div to the right of the screen and as soon as you subtract the width of the div from the right, it'll disappear from the screen.

But is should be either positioned absolute or fixed.

Comment: I am sorry , I am trying to send it left. Yes, it has absolute positioning. I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can ge the width ofthe page and then usethe following

```
$("elem").animate({"left":$(window).width()+640});
```

Replace the elem With your element object

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question again. My animation should be to left direction. I think I have to modify your code as to the right.